# Where is the best place to practice parrying?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am well informed in how to parry, but I haven't mastered parrying with all weapons. I would like to find a area that spawns slow moving, slowly attacking monsters in low numbers (I would also appreciate you telling me the nearest bonfire).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **Cardinal Tower Bonfire** as starting point. From there you have quick access to a lot of different Hollow mobs. These mobs have a variety of weapons, and attack with different speeds, and are great to practice parrying.

Additionally, they do not hit very hard. All in all, it is a area where you can easily control the settings and the pulls. If you blow out the wall, you'll have even more mobs to choose from very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am parrying a little better, but sometimes more than one mob comes after me. It may be a bit bothersome at times, but they aren't hard to put down.